# How do I make an unban command on Discord Bots C#?

Tags: c#, discord.net

So I am making an unban command for my discord bot and it isn't working. Whenever I execute the command, it won't work. Here is the code

```
public async Task unban(IGuildUser user)
{
    await user.Guild.RemoveBanAsync(user);
    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Unbanned {user}");
}
```

By the way, can you explain what the solution does because I am very new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Command("unban")]
public async Task UnbanTask(SocketGuildUser user)
{
    await user.Guild.RemoveBanAsync(user);
    await ReplyAsync($"Unbanned {user.Username}");
}
```

This seems to be your approach to ban a user which is very correct. However there are a few things that can go wrong. 
First you need `[RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.BanMembers)]` under the `Command` to make sure that the bot has the permission to ban/unban a user. 
Secondly the bot probably cant ban an Admin.

And the **main thing** is that this command required you to mention a user that is banned. This isn't very feasible. So here is the solution. `RemoveBanAsync` has an overload.

[image: Overloads]

So just pass in the userID in the `RemoveBanAsync` method.

```
[Command("unban")]
[RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.BanMembers)]
public async Task UnbanTask(ulong userId)
{
    await Context.Guild.RemoveBanAsync(userId);
    // Unbanned
}
```

You can find the docs [Here](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/blob/82cfdffc6516e17ea86013e550060bb6df59a016/src/Discord.Net.WebSocket/Entities/Guilds/SocketGuild.cs#L301-L302)

Comment: This works but is there a way to type in the username to unban someone instead of their user Id?

Comment: @ChristopherIsFun I could be wrong but I don't think you can mention someone who was banned from your server. So what you are asking isn't gonna work anyways. But since it is there I'm pretty sure there is a damn good reason why it is there. 
But as far as I can say there isn't a solution to your aspects.